# Web scraping of nested links with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to web scrap the links that are nested in the name of the property, this script works, however, not retrieves the URLs only `NA`s. Could you help me or what I am missing in the script snipped.

Thank you

```
# Test
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno?_escaped_fragment_="
page <- read_html(link)

price <- page %>% 
  html_elements(".norm-price.ng-binding") %>% 
  html_text()

name <- page %>% 
  html_elements(".name.ng-binding") %>% 
  html_text()

location <- page %>% 
  html_elements(".locality.ng-binding") %>% 
  html_text()

href <- page %>% 
  html_nodes(".name.ng-binding") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.sreality.cz", ., sep="")

flat <- data.frame(price, name, location, href, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selector picked the anchors' inline html instead of the anchor. This should work:

```
 page %>% 
     html_nodes("a.title") %>%
     html_attr("ng-href") %>% 
     paste0("https://www.sreality.cz", .)
```

`paste0(...)` being a shorthand for `paste(..., sep = '')`

Comment: Wow, it works thank you, how did you get the "a.title" and "ng-href" do I have to search via inspecting the website?

Comment: you guessed it :-) I used the element picker (Ctrl-Shift-C in Chrome) to select the link and display its html surroundings in the document inspector. From there I chose element type ('a' for anchor = link), class ('title') and attribute ('ng-href') as a quick'n'dirty selector. Had that been too generic, I'd have made the selector more specific as @NadPat suggested or filtered the results, e.g. for 'detail/prodej' in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using JS path

```
page %>% 
  html_nodes('#page-layout > div.content-cover > div.content-inner > div.transcluded-content.ng-scope > div > div > div.content > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(n)') %>% 
  html_nodes('a') %>% html_attr('href') %>% str_subset('detail') %>% unique() %>% paste("https://www.sreality.cz", ., sep="")

[1] "https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/4+1/brno-zabrdovice-tkalcovska/1857071452"          
 [2] "https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/3+kk/brno--/1336764508"                             
 [3] "https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/2+kk/brno-stary-liskovec-u-posty/3639359836"        
 [4] "https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/2+1/brno-reckovice-druzstevni/3845994844"           
 [5] "https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/2+1/brno-styrice-jilova/1102981468"                 
 [6] "https://www.sreality.cz/detail/prodej/byt/1+kk/brno-dolni-herspice-/1961502812"
```